# How do I fix SQL Server assembly optimization errors and memory exhaustion?

Tags: sql-server-2012

The .NET Runtime Optimization Service (`mscorsvw`) keeps consuming all my workstation's memory since I installed SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1.

It consumes about 1.6 GB of memory before exhausting all available memory:

[image: .NET Runtime Optimization Service consumes all available memory on my workstation.]

I can kill the process, but it happens again when I restart my computer or wait long enough.

[Techdows](http://techdows.com/2010/08/what-is-mscorsvw-exe-how-to-disable-it.html) suggests using the .NET Native Image Generator (`ngen`) to solve the problem.

I oipened a Command Prompt and ran commands like this:

```
cd C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.1
ngen executeQueuedItems
```

The memory consumption of `mscorsvw` dropped to about 20-30 MB, and `ngen` consumed all the remaining memory.

`ngen` generated only error messages until I killed the process. The first few lines of output looked like this:

```
Microsoft (R) CLR Native Image Generator - Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Failed to load dependency Microsoft.DataWarehouse of assembly
Microsoft.SqlServer.MaintenancePlanTasks, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 because of the following error : The system
cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
Failed to load dependency Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataTools.Interop of assembly 
Microsoft.DataWarehouse, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 because of the following error : The system
cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
Failed to load dependency Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI of assembly
Microsoft.DataWarehouse, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 because of the following error : The located
assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

All the messsages say either that the system could not find an assembly, or that a manifest definition does not match a reference.

As a workaround, I have disabled the Windows Services `clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_32` and `clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_64`.

This hides the problem rather than solving it, and stops all .NET assemblies from being optimized.

What else can I try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem is described on Connect (see [msiexec.exe processes keep running after installation of SQL Server 2012 SP1](https://web.archive.org/web/20160322031752/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/770630/msiexec-exe-processes-keep-running-after-installation-of-sql-server-2012-sp1)) and a hotfix is available at [KB2793634](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36215). There are work-arounds listed on the [Connect post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160322031752/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/770630/msiexec-exe-processes-keep-running-after-installation-of-sql-server-2012-sp1) and [this blog](http://blog.ittoby.com/2012/12/sql-2012-msiexecexe-running-constantly.html) if you are unable to install the hotfix immediately.

I chose to setup 2 scripts.  1st script runs daily at 1am, and set to terminate after 1 hour of execution

```
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe executequeueditems
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe executequeueditems
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe executequeueditems 
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe executequeueditems
```

2nd script runs daily at 3am (and whenever the computer restarts):

```
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe queue pause
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe queue pause
```

This way I still get compile optimization jobs (only run during off-peak hours), but the `mscorsvw`/`msiexec` process is tamed.